# Calling jar from terminal vs calling jar from class file

Tags: java, jar

I have a problem where I can successfully call the jar file from the terminal but I can't call it successfully from another Java file.  As you can see it works properly from the terminal.

[image]

However, it returns null when called from a class file despite feeding in the same arguments.

[image]

The relevant bit of code would appear to call the jar file the same way.

```
try{

        String output = "java -jar Translator.jar " + word;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(output);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);

        while ((line = in.readLine())!= null) {
            line = in.readLine();
            line = line.trim();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you check the location of Translator.jar It should be in the running directory?
What is your .jar file's location (path)

Comment: Interesting.  I think it might be a problem with the setup of intellij, the ide im using.  I went to the production folder and called the classfile manually and everything worked fine.